# How to ask questions on this site?

Tags: support, faq, asking-questions

What are the kinds of questions one should ask on this site? The following will cover:

- How to prevent my question from being down-voted and/or closed?
- What kinds of questions are considered good, on-topic questions on this site?
- What to do to make sure my question gets the best chances of good answers?
- What kinds of questions are considered off topic on this site?

  - Where can I ask them in that case?
- What is considered a not constructive question?

Comment: Note, this question is community wiki! Anyone with more than 10 reputation points can edit it and any answer it may have. The point is that the entire community will take part in the making of this question and the other [meta-tag:faq] pages.

Comment: related: http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-to-write-a-good-question-or-improve-quality-of-an-existing-question. I would be glad if you could make that a community-wiki, too.

Comment: Done, next time please flag that question and write that you want it to CW there. Thanks =).

Answer (score 3):

### What kinds of questions are considered good, on topic questions on this site?

On [Anime and Manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/), questions are expected to generally revolve around... Anime and Manga.

We expect questions to relate to one or more of the following:

- A specific anime and/or manga series. (For example, [naruto](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naruto), [bleach](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bleach), [death-note](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death-note)).
- Anime and/or manga in general. (For example, [anime-identification](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-identification), [anime-production](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-production))

Most other questions will be rejected as off-topic, and either closed or migrated to a different site.

### What to do to make sure my question gets the best chances of getting good answers?

The secret is to make the question easy to read and understand.

Read the question again after writing it. Ask yourself:

1. Is my question easy to read?

   - Is the grammar correct?
   - Are there any spelling mistakes?
   - Make sure to divide the question into well formatted paragraphs, don't just throw a giant block of text, no one will read it all?
2. Is my title "attractive" enough?

   - Don't include tags in your title. (i.e. Don't ask "**Naruto - What are Madara Uchiha's Weaknesses?**", ask "**What are Madara Uchiha's Weaknesses in Naruto?**").
   - Is it clear? Will an expert want to check it out?
3. Is my question answerable?

   - Is the question explained thoroughly?
   - Read the question thoroughly, is what you're asking clear enough?
   - Remember that us readers have no crystal balls, we don't know what went through your head when you wrote the question!

### What kinds of questions are considered *off topic* on this site?

Any question which doesn't directly relate to Anime and Manga in general, or a specific anime or manga series, is considered off topic. This includes (but not limited to):

- Questions about the process of anime creations, and/or software.
- Questions about resources for reading/viewing anime/manga online.
- Questions regarding non-Japanese cartoons/comics.

#### Where can I ask those in that case?

It usually depends on the topic of the question.

- Questions regarding anime/manga software should probably go to [Audio and Video Production](https://video.stackexchange.com/) or to [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) respectively.
- Questions about resources for reading/viewing anime/manga online are generally *illegal*. They will not be accepted on any Stack Exchange site.
- Questions regarding non-Japanese cartoons/comic can probably go to [Movies and TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/).

### What is considered a not constructive question?

A question is considered not constructive if it cannot be reasonably answered. It generally happens when there are no (and can almost never be) any facts supporting the answers given.

A few specific examples are:

- Questions about future events. The question will remain unanswered until the even happens. Once it happens, the question will be useless.
- Questions regarding the author's reasoning. We don't (and can't) know what the author was thinking when he made Piccolo blow the moon up, so please don't ask us *why* (**How** he did it is a whole different story).